# loading async component with parameter in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, router, react-router-v4

i have async component where everything works fine,but when i try to pass parameter in `path` like /home/:id?,then it fail to load and giving error 
**Loading chunk failed.**

please help me how to pass parameter correctly using "react-router": "^4.2.0"

```
<Switch>
 <Route path={`${match.url}home/:id?`} component={asyncComponent(() => 
     import('../containers/home'))}/>
 <Route path={`${match.url}dash`} exact component={asyncComponent(() => 
     import('../containers/dash'))}/>
</Switch>
```

> async.js

```
 export default function asyncComponent(importComponent) {
class AsyncFunc extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            component: null
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        Nprogress.start();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.mounted = false;
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.mounted = true;
        const {default: Component} = await importComponent();
        Nprogress.done();
        if (this.mounted) {
            this.setState({
                component: <Component {...this.props} />
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const Component = this.state.component || <div/>;
        return (
            <ReactPlaceholder type="text" rows={7} ready={Component !== 
    null}>
                {Component}
            </ReactPlaceholder>
        );
    }
}

 return AsyncFunc;
}
```

Comment: why did you add the '?' after ':id'?

Comment: @nirit-levi it would maybe any optional thing so

Answer (score 0):

If you using webpack in your project, the code below may be help you.

```
output: { filename: '[name].js', chunkFilename: 'js/[name].app.js', publicPath: '/' }
```

As you see. It's simply changes directory of chunkFilename and public path.